# For similar triangles ADG, BDF, and CDE, find EF given AB, BC, and DE

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was tutoring a student today and one of the practice problems we were working on asked the question posed in the title, including an image like the one below. The quadrilaterals each represent a car in a train in a perspective sketch with the triangle CDE representing all of the following cars to the vanishing point on the horizon.
[The triangles in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzrAk.jpg)

After looking at the problem, neither of us could see how to find the length of EF with the given information and we moved on. Is there a solution that we missed or is this problem just missing information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to apply the the intercept theorem (a.k.a Thales' Theorem) three times. First,
$$\frac{1.9}{8.4}=\frac{EF}{FG}=\frac{1.9k}{8.4k}$$
Now, focus on $\bigtriangleup DBF$ to find CD in terms of $K$.
$$\frac{5.4}{1.9k}=\frac{CD}{BC}=\frac{\frac{5.4}{k}}{1.9} \implies CD=\frac{5.4}{k}$$
Finally, focus on $\bigtriangleup ADG$ to find $k$.

$$\frac{\frac{5.4}{k}+1.9}{8.4}=\frac{5.4+1.9k}{8.4k}$$

I believe $k$ turns out to be exactly $1$ and hence, $EF=1.9$ units.